# How to input the header from user

Tags: python, pycurl

I want to add value to receive input from the user to the header .

But, An error occurs due to two variables(x_user, x_key) when declare a variable header .

**1. Stored in list the user data in file.csv**

command of input is

```
ID = input("input the customer email id: ")
cList(ID)


def cList(value):
    with open(DIR, newline='') as f:
        data = csv.reader(open(DIR, "r"))
        for row in data:
            MEM_ID = row[0]
            MEM_SQ = row[1]
            X_AUTH_USER = row[2]
            X_AUTH_KEY = row[3]
            X_STORAGE_URL = row[4]
            ACCESSKEY = row[5]
```

**2. It assigns the variables to the function.**

```
aList( X_AUTH_USER, X_AUTH_KEY)`
```

**3. Function of aList used the pycurl module.**

```
def aList(x_user, x_key):
        headers = ['X-Storage-User:'x_user, 'X-Storage-Pass:'x_key]
        pycurl_connect = pycurl.Curl()
        pycurl_connect.setop(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
        pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.URL, STORAGE_URL)
        pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, bodycb)
        pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, headercb)
        pycurl_connect.perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question. (Not used the pycurl)

requests module is a very good library.

```
def gList(auth_url,auth_token):
container = input("inpurt container: ")
headers = {'X-Auth-Token':auth_token}
req = requests.get(auth_url+container, headers=headers)
print(req.headers)
```